# Sort integer by absolute value

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a list of integers and i want to sort it with `sort` but i want to sort on the absolute value of the integers. For example `7 0 5 10 -2` should give `0 -2 5 7 10` (integers are separated on multiple lines in my file)

I don't think there is an option in `sort` to do that but i can't find an other command to sort lines. The `-n` options sort with the natural order and `-g` is not what i want.

I tried to look at `awk` but i don't know if it can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
cat numbers.txt | sed -r 's/-([0-9]+)/\1-/g;' | sort -n | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)-/-\1/g;'
```

- the first `sed` put the minus behind the digits
- `sort` sort by number
- the second `sed` puts the minus again in front of the digits

Comment: Good use of pipelines to solve this problem. the `cat`  isn't strictly needed, as you can do `sed -r '....' numbers.txt | sort ...` Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find this documented anywhere, but when you run `sort -Vd` it sorts by absolute value. It's a combination of the "version sort" and "numerical sort" options. With `1 5 3 7 -2 -4 -9`, version sort on it's own does something like this:

```
1
3
5
7
-2
-4
-9
```

And numerical sort on its own sorts like this;

```
-9
-4
-2
1
3
5
7
```

And with both options, it sorts like this;

```
1
-2
3
-4
5
7
-9
```

I don't know if this is by design or by accident, and I've only tested it in GNU sort. I have found this trick to be very useful for certain code golfing situations.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the error "sort: options `-dV' are incompatible"

Comment: @OverlordAlex idk, it still works for me. I'm using GNU sort, you're probably using BSD or something like that. This is not portable, I guess.

Comment: ref - https://man.archlinux.org/man/sort.1.en . `-dV` uses the trick combining directory-order and version-sort. directory-order ignores the minus sign. And version-sort "sort of" like numeric-sort. **But** version-sort puts 10.4 before 10.04 as it sorts one decimal place before two decimal places. This could produce wrong results in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

A one line perl solution.  Works more generally on floating point values as well. For example:

```
$ cat numbers.txt
1 -100 5 -4 7 -9 12 25.3 1.8 -1 33.5

$ perl -lane 'print(join " ", sort {abs($a) <=> abs($b)} @F);' numbers.txt
1 -1 1.8 -4 5 7 -9 12 25.3 33.5 -100
```

If you want the order to be descending, just reverse the `$a` and `$b` variables.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is named `fname` then the following should work:

```
paste <(sed 's/-//' fname) fname | sort -n | cut -f 2
```

The `sed` strips out the `-` to generate an absolute value, `paste`, joins the absolute value as the first column, by which is then `sort`ed.  This is then `cut` out.